# Negate a character group to replace all other characters

Tags: regex, kotlin, time

I have the following string:

```
"Thu Dec 31 22:00:00 UYST 2009"
```

I want to replace everything except for the hours and minutes so I get the following result:

```
"22:00"
```

I am using this regex :

```
(^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]))
```

But its not matching anything.

This would be my line of actual code :

```
println("Thu Dec 31 22:00:00 UYST 2009".replace("(^([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]))".toRegex(),""))
```

Can someone help me to correct the regex?

Comment: `^`  means: start of string, when outside of character group, inside it means: `none of these characters`.

Comment: `^.*(\d\d:\d\d):.*$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/l81ZiV/1/)

Comment: I know this is a question about regex shenanigans, but if you're actually trying to pull a time from a datetime string, I'd definitely work with a datetime library if it's an option (e.g. this breaks if a leading zero is omitted, like ``1:00`` but a format string with ``h:mm`` would match that as well as two-digit hours)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the one you have isn't working is because you are asserting that the line starts right before the minutes and seconds, which isn't the case. This can be fixed by removing the assertion (`^`).

If you need the assertion to remain, there is another way. In most languages, you wouldn't be able to use a variable-length positive lookbehind here, but lucky for you, it looks like you can in Kotlin.

A positive lookbehind is basically just telling the pattern "*this* comes before what I'm looking for". It's denoted by a group beginning with `?<=`. In this case, you can use something like `(?<=^[\w ]+)`. This will match all word characters or spaces between the beginning of the line and where the pattern that comes after it is able to match. Appending it to your expression would look something like `(?<=^[\w ]+)([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9])` (note you will have to escape the `\w` in order for it to be in a string and not be angry about it).

Side note, Yogesh_D is correct in saying that `\d\d:\d\d` is the same as your `[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]`. Using this, it would look more like `(?<=^[\w ]+)\d\d:\d\d`.

Answer (score 1):

You may use various solutions, here are two:

```kotlin
val text = """Thu Dec 31 22:00:00 UYST 2009"""
val match = """\b(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d\b""".toRegex().find(text)
println(match?.value)
    
val match2 = """\b(\d{1,2}:\d{2}):\d{2}\b""".toRegex().find(text)
println(match2?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1))
```

[Both return](https://ideone.com/2rrgUq) `22:00`. See [regex #1 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmCQ9Z/4) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/EmCQ9Z/3).

The regex complexity should be selected based on how messy the input string is.

*Details*

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])` - an optional zero and then a non-zero digit, or `1` and any digit, or `2` and a digit from `0` to `3`
- `:` - a `:` char
- `[0-5]\d` - `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` or `5` and then any one digit
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If there is a match with this regex, you get it as a whole match, so you can access it via `match?.value`.

If you do not have to worry about any pre-valiation when matching, you may simply match 3 colon-separated digit pairs and capture the first two, see the second regex:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d{1,2}:\d{2})` - Group 1: one or two digits, `:` and two digits
- `:\d{2}` - a `:` and two digits (not captured)
- `\b` - a word boundary.

If there is a match, we need Group 1 value, hence `match2?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)` is used.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what language you are using but why use negation when you can directly match the first digits in the hh:mm format.
Assuming that the date string format always is in the format with a hh:mm in there.

This regex snippet should have the first group match the hh:mm.

https://regex101.com/r/aHdehZ/1

The regex to use is `(\d\d:\d\d)`